# Тестирование блокчейна на локалке

Tags: python, postman, blockchain

В конце лета потянуло в крипту, решил подробно разобраться, как работает блокчейн. Понятно, что чтобы лучше разобраться, лучше сделать свой. Нашел туториал в интернете, вот ссылка:

```
https://python-scripts.com/blockchain
```

Писал по нему. Всё шло хорошо, пока не началась часть с тестированием через несколько узлов. Так почти в самом конце есть фрагмент следующий текста

```
Теперь вы можете сесть за другой компьютер (если хотите), и развернуть разные узлы в своей сети. Также вы можете развернуть процессы при помощи различных портов на одном и том же компьютере. Я развернул еще один узел на своем компьютере, но на другом порте и зарегистрировал его при помощи моего текущего узла. Таким образом, я получил два узла: http://localhost:5000 и http://localhost:5001.
```

Пожалуйста, объясните максимально подробно, что он тут сделал. Объясните пж прям как для чайника, как сделать то, что там написано: как развернуть второй узел на другом порту и зарегистрировать его. Потому что я сидел несколько дней и реально не понимал, что там происходит. Stackoverflow -- последняя надежда.

Comment: Ну, здравый смысл подсказывает, что это подразумевает повторение всех ранее описанных действий, просто вместо 5000 указать 5001 и всё

Comment: Видимо, можно даже просто заменить 5000 на чтение значения порта откуда-нибудь (например из аргумента командной строки) да и всё

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать на винде 10

Comment: Если вы не знаете, как считывать аргументы командной строки, то, вероятно, вам стоит почитать какой-нибудь учебник по основам Python